# Zend Framework Bootstrap with Layout?

Tags: zend-framework

So, I have a problem and I have been searching forever about how to do this.

I want to have several project directories on my shared host but I want to be able to hit the public directory when someone types in the root directory for that project. I can't edit the httpd.conf to set up virtual hosts so I have been looking for alternative solutions.

Account Structure

/public_html

.../Project1

....../application

....../public

I stumbled on http://www.mauriciocuenca.com/blog/2009/03/two-or-more-zend-framework-projects-on-a-shared-host/ and followed the steps (modifying some stuff since it is outdated)

And I can get a single view to show up. The problem is, if I create a layout I can't get anything but the normal view to display. I think I am just missing a simple hook up.

Is the above solution the best for my situation?

Comment: It looks like the setup you are using is fine, and should work.  Where do you setup your layout?  Do you have a line like this in your bootstrap:  `Zend_Layout::startMvc(APPLICATION_PATH . "/layouts/scripts");`  If so, please show us this, and where any constants in it are defined.

Comment: I think it is just specified in my application.ini
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

Comment: Stuck it here in my index.php file and it worked. Is there a way to set the base path inside zend so I can reference my stuff like "/images/blah.jpg" instead of using relative paths?  `Zend_Layout::startMvc(APP_PATH . "/layouts/scripts");


$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();  


$front->setControllerDirectory(CONTROLLERS_PATH);  

$front->dispatch();`

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not 100% clear, I can't figure out that you want to serve one site per shared host directory or all site from the same directory.

Although you can't edit httpd.conf, you can use .htaccess file. While using Zend you already use .htaccess (located in public dir). So you can write rules to make url based redirections.

Comment: I am doing both.
I mostly need to just take care of the virtual host problem.